# Can I get response headers with devour js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, httpresponse

actually I am working on a Vue js project that uses devour js to consume endpoints. Now I need to get a response header(new_token_access in the image).

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJECV.png)

Is there a way to get all response headers?. Thanks a lot!

https://github.com/twg/devour/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like devour uses axios as the http client. You can set up response interceptors to capture the response object and get the header values.

See: https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors